# Git merge does not deleting files from another repository

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote, svnsync

Two repositories exist: rep1, rep2.
Both are results of one-way syncs from the same SVN instance. (The changes in SVN are synched to git, but the changes in git are not synched back to SVN)
the two repositories are not forks of each other.

rep1/master branch contains a file file1.txt

rep2/master branch contained the file file1.txt, but the file was deleted in rep2/

rep2 is added as a remote in rep1 in order to merge. (remot2)

branch rep2/master is created

```
git checkout -b rep2_master_branch --track rep2/master
```

a "merge" branch is created from the tip of rep1/master

```
git checkout -b merge-master-branches master
```

Execute a merge with option "theirs" and squash.
allow-unrelated-histories is required as the merge comes from another server.

```
git merge -Xtheirs --squash rep2_master_branch  --allow-unrelated-histories
```

What is observed is that rep1/file1.txt is NOT deleted.

Further observations, conflicts during the merge are correctly resolved, as are modififed and added files. It seems that the only omission are files that have been deleted in rep2.

How can I work around this? or better yet, how can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as Git is concerned, that *is* the correct merge result.

Git's `git merge` works by comparing two branch tips to a common merge base.  That is, if you draw the commit graph, and it looks like this:

```
             o--o--L   <-- branch1
            /
...--o--o--*
            \
             o--o--R   <-- branch2
```

then the result of merging `branch1` (commit `L`) with `branch2` (commit `R`) will be computed by comparing the contents of commit `*`, the common point from which both branches derive, to the contents of commit `L` and to the contents of commit `R`.

Whatever changed from `*` to `L` happened in the left side.  Whatever changed from `*` to `R` happened in the right side.  Git combines these two "things that happened", applies those combined changes to the contents of `*`, and if all goes well, makes a new commit from the result.

But you are using `--allow-unrelated-histories`.  This is required *only* when there *is no common commit:* we draw the history of `L` and `R` and find that they never diverged from a common point.  For instance, we might get:

```
A--o--o--...--L   <-- branch1

B--o--...--o--R   <-- branch2
```

where `A` and `B` are *both* root commits.  So what *should* Git use as the common starting point, to figure out what changed since then?

One can argue for various starting-points of one's choice, but Git's answer is: *Use an empty commit.*  That is, with `--allow-unrelated-histories`, Git pretends there's a common commit that has no files at all:

```
  A--o--o--...--L   <-- branch1
 /
*
 \
  B--o--...--o--R   <-- branch2
```

Comparing commit `*`, which is empty, to commit `L`, Git finds that every file on `branch1` is newly created in the form that it has in `L`.  Comparing `*` to `R`, Git finds that every file on `branch2` is newly created in the form that it has in `R`.  Wherever those files match, everything is fine: we just take that file.  Wherever `L` has a file that `R` doesn't or vice versa, everything is fine: we just take that file.  Wherever both `L` and `R` have a file, but their contents differ, we have a merge conflict.

Since you used `-X theirs`, Git resolves each conflict by taking "their" changes ("theirs" being the commit you named, rather than the one you were on as `HEAD`) since the empty merge-base commit.

If you want Git to pretend that some other commit is the merge base, you can use `git replace --graft` to insert some fake parent linkage.  For instance, suppose you want to fake-tie the two together at arbitrarily-chosen commit C:

```
A--o--o--...--L   <-- branch1
         /
B--...--C--...--R   <-- branch2
```

so that Git will compare `C` to `L`, and `C` to `R`.  As far as `git merge` itself goes, it doesn't matter which commit you choose in the `A--...--L` chain; *any* commit will do (including `A` and `L` themselves), but note that Git will only "see" changes since the commit you pick (due to diffing `C`-vs-`L`, and `C`-vs-`R`).  So, pick some appropriate commit in the chain and run:

```
git replace --graft <hash-ID-of-chosen-commit> <hash-ID-of-C>
```

and Git will now use the replacement (graft) commit instead of the chosen commit.  A `git merge` will now use the contents of `C` as the common source.  (You can delete the graft as soon as `git merge` exits, even if it exits with a merge conflict.  Hence you can write a tiny script that inserts the graft, runs `git merge`, and deletes the graft, to merge with arbitrarily-chosen ancestor.  Just insert it as the replacement for `L` as long as it's on the `B--...--R` line, or insert it as the replacement for `R` as long as it's on the `A--...--L` line.)

Comment: Thanks for a very clear explanation, it brought me to the answer.
I would add a note however, that there was one details that was slightly misleading. 

 "any commit will do" : this is only true once you consider that only changes "after" the chosen commit will be taken into account during the merge. So in my case, files were deleted on branch1 in commit Y, so I MUST choose a commit X to replace C that occurs before Y.

(I`m only noting this for anyone else that might be reading this might find it useful. )
Other than that, the why and the inner workings were very clearly explained.

Comment: Ah, right, if you want Git to see some particular changes at the two branch tips `L` and `R`, you need to choose a base `C` that (as compared to `L` and `R`) does not have those changes yet.